# Constraints on closed type families?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'd like to write a horribly non-parametric version of a function of type

```
pretty :: (Show a) => a -> Text
```

such that

```
pretty :: Text -> Text = id
pretty :: String -> Text = T.pack
pretty :: (Show a) => a -> Text = T.pack . show
```

So the idea is that anything that already has a `Show` instance can be turned into a "pretty" `Text` by just `show`-ing it, except for `Text` and `String` which we want to special-case.

The following code works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, ConstraintKinds #-}
module Pretty (pretty) where

import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

type family StringLike a :: Bool where
    StringLike String = True
    StringLike Text = True
    StringLike a = False

class (b ~ StringLike a) => Pretty' a b where
    pretty' :: a -> Text

instance Pretty' String True where
    pretty' = T.pack

instance Pretty' Text True where
    pretty' = id

instance (Show a, StringLike a ~ False) => Pretty' a False where
    pretty' = T.pack . show

type Pretty a = (Pretty' a (StringLike a))

pretty :: (Pretty a) => a -> Text
pretty = pretty'
```

and it can be used without exporting anything except the `pretty` function.

However, I am not too happy about the type signature for `pretty`:

```
pretty :: (Pretty a) => a -> Text
```

I feel that since `StringLike` is a closed type family, there should be a way for GHC to figure out that if only `(Show a)` holds, `(Pretty a)` is already satisfied, since:

1. The following hold trivially just by substituting the results of applying `StringLike`:

   ```
   (StringLike String ~ True, Pretty' String True)
   (StringLike Text ~ True, Pretty' Text True)
   ```
2. For everything else, we *also* know the result of applying `StringLike`:

   ```
   (Show a, StringLike a ~ False) => (Pretty' a (StringLike a))
   ```

Is there a way to convince GHC of this?

Comment: A 'ha-ha just serious' idea just occured to me which is to import `Prelude` qualified, and rename `Pretty` to `Show`...

Comment: "I feel that since StringLike is a closed type family, there should be a way for GHC to figure out that if only (Show a) holds," I think the following is a big problem: `StringLike` yields a type of kind(-lifted) `Bool`, `Show` yields a type of kind `Constraint`. It's not just that GHC doesn't understand the relationship; they actually follow different laws of logic. With lifted `Bool`, you assume the law of the excluded middle, but with `Constraint`, you may not rely on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I feel that since `StringLike` is a closed type family, there should be a way for GHC to figure out that if only `(Show a)` holds, `(Pretty a)` is already satisfied

To do that would require type inspection, and would break parameteric polymorphism. Consider defining a type family

```
type family IsInt a :: Bool where
  IsInt Int = True
  IsInt a = False
class (b ~ IsInt a) => TestInt a b where
  isInt :: a -> Bool
instance TestInt Int True where
  isInt _ = True
instance (IsInt a ~ False) => TestInt a False where
  isInt _ = False
```

Now by your argument, GHC should be able to satisfy `TestInt a` from `()`. In other words, we should be able to test for any given type whether it is equal to Int. This is clearly impossible.

Similarly, a `Show a` dictionary is equivalent to a function `a -> ShowS`. How would you be able to decide, given just that, whether the argument is `StringLike`?

Comment: "In other words, we should be able to test for any given type whether it is equal to `Int`. This is clearly impossible." Is it? Don't we already need this for e.g. type unification? What am I missing here?

Comment: So basically your point is that we can only prove `(Show a) => (Pretty a)`, in some sense, non-constructively?

Comment: Isn't `IsInt` already possible with http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/candidate/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#t:-61--61-?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstood your goal but this seems like a lot of work to get the type you want.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances #-}
module Prettied where 

import Data.Text (Text, pack)

class Pretty a where pretty :: a -> Text 

instance           Pretty Text   where pretty = id 
instance           Pretty String where pretty = pack 
instance Show a => Pretty a      where pretty = pack . show
```

While it may seem that `pretty` should have type `Pretty a => a -> Text`, due to `IncoherentInstances` it will actually have type `Show a => a -> Text`. This should probably be in its own module because enabling `IncoherentInstances` is one of those things that can break valid code.

Comment: I would strongly advise against the use of `IncoherentInstances`. With this definition, `pretty "foo"` results in `"foo"`. But if you add `pretty2 x = pretty x`, then `pretty2 "foo"` results in `"\"foo\""`. Not very robust or predictable.

Comment: Yeah, the goal is to do this without nasty stuff like `IncoherentInstances` or `UndecideableInstances`.

Comment: just `OverlappingInstances` works here. I think we're just at a bit of an awkward stage where we don't have the function-level analog to go with closed type families, so we can define these kinds of things fairly easily, but have to uses type classes (which we can't close), OverlappingInstances, UndecidableInstances, etc